# Can the HTML data attribute hold a reference to a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is it possible with the HTML `data-` attributes to hold a reference to another DOM element? For example, I could do this with jQuery:

```
var domel1 = document.getElementById("#mydiv")
var domel2 = document.getElementById("#mydiv2")
$(domEl1).attr('data-domel', domel2)
```

Then later on, with jQuery I would do:

```
var domel1 = document.getElementById("#mydiv")
var domel2 = $(domel2).data('domel')
$(domel2).html("blahblahblah")
```

This might seem like a trivial example because I could just reference `domel2` with the same `id` like I did at first, but there are cases where this could be useful for representing relationships between `<div>`s.

Comment: You can't store the DOM element itself, but you can store the selector string and then pass that to jQuery.

Comment: You can use jQuery's `.data()` method to store any jQuery object, but it won't be written back to the DOM.

Comment: I think your code is a cross between jQuery and JavaScript :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes and no. You cannot store a reference to a DOM element in a `data-` attribute. However, you can associated a reference to a DOM element to another element using jQuery `.data()`, which are already using:

```
$someElement.data('name', someOtherElement);
```

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

> The .data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM
>   elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore
>   from memory leaks.

Note that using `.data()` to set data will add it to the data store but not add it as a `data-` attribute in the DOM. However, using `.data()` to read data will check the data store as well as the `data-` attribute (if one exists and there's no data store value with the given key).

Answer (score 4):

Not directly. `data-*` attributes are just attributes, so you can only store a string in them.

But, of course, you can store the id or class of your target element, in order to retrieve it later.

Or you could also store a reference to the element in a property, since properties can have any value.

Comment: Why a downvote? If my answer is not correct in some way, I want to know that.

Comment: Curious about that as well. OP asks if it can be stored in `HTML data- attribute`, not an array or another object. As such it is a definitive no.

Comment: @user13500 When somebody ask you cross a sea by walk, I would say you can't walk over a sea but you can use boat instead. Nothing wrong about it :)

Answer (score 2):

Not legal, since attributes should be text strings. But since you're using jQuery you could use the `.data()` method instead.

Comment: I am not sure why downvote to this answer? This answer is correct and to the person who has downvoted I would like to have a clear idea that jQuery is just library of JavaScript it is not a language. It is illegal or not allowed to store DOM element as an attribute in actual DOM. @Stephen is correct

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `.data()` basically does everything for you.

But if you cannot use jQuery, or have to implement something more case-specific, you can hold indexes to a global object that holds the actual data.
This way you can support any type of data you need, references, objects, functions (even binded functions).

Here's a vanilla implementation of data, though I'm not sure what are your limitations - you will probably want to change some bits of the code below.
Note that elements in this code are identified by using their id.

```
// Set data with: elem.data('key',anything)
// Get data with: elem.data('key')
// Remove data (kind of) with: elem.data('key',undefined)

// This will generate random id on element if id is missing
Node.prototype.force_id = function() {
    return this.id || (this.id = ('' + Math.random()).replace('0.', 'id-'));
}

// Our own data implementation
window.DATAOFDOM = {}; // I like naming globals as ALLCAPS
Node.prototype.data = function(k, v) {
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        // getter
        if (window.DATAOFDOM[this.id]) {
            return window.DATAOFDOM[this.id][k]; // returns undefined when k isn't there
        }
        // else: implicitly returns undefined when there's no data for this element
    } else {
        // setter
        this.force_id();
        if (!window.DATAOFDOM[this.id])
            window.DATAOFDOM[this.id] = {};
        return window.DATAOFDOM[this.id][k] = v;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oriadam/63zn9qtd/

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer because no element can store DOM element as an attribute value. Here is a small polyfill to do the same

If I have the same requirement I would follow this approach,

```
 var DataDOM = (function(){
     function DataDOM(){}
     var elements = {}, counter = 0;
     DataDOM.prototype.set = function(ele){
         elements['ele' + counter] = ele;
         counter += 1;
         return ele + (counter - 1);
     }
     DataDOM.prototype.get = function(eleRef){
         return elements[eleRef];
     }
     return DataDOM;
 })();
```

Use like below

```
 var dDOM = new DataDOM();
```

For example if if I want to set DOM reference to a element data attribute

```
var div = document.getElementById('someId');
var attr = dDOM.set(div);
```

Then set `attr` as data to some element

then while retrieving use below method to get it back

```
 var referedElement = dDOM.get(someElement.attr('data'));
```

Because there is no direct way to store elements as Data AFAIK.

Comment: `'ele' + counter` is not necessary. For that matter, you can just use a normal array and return the index as a string - no need to mess around with counters. ;) (sort of like simulating a pointer value)